TOML validation: "Additional properties not allowed"
I created a file named pricing.toml in VS Code. I have an Even Better TOML plugin installed that checks the syntax. Whatever I write in this file, the plugin gives me an error "Additional properties not allowed", with all the keys listed.
I tried renaming the file and the funny thing is - it works with any other name except pricing.toml! It's kinda funny, but I really need the file to be named exactly pricing.toml and not anything else, but at the same time, I don't want any validation errors either...
Reproducible (maybe?) example:

test = 1

[other]
test2 = "string"


After renaming to prices.toml:



@Dolphin, nope; I still don't understand why this is happening.
